# Remove the spaces in the Bibliography in memoir class

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, memoir

I am using a `memoir` class in my master thesis, but when I generate the Bibliography it always have spaces between the fields like below.

[image]

I have tried many commands like `\noindent` but still looks the same.

Does anyone know how to arrange the Bibliography to appears with no spaces between the fields like the normal Bibliography?

Comment: That is not the normal `memoir` style. Provide a MWE (a minimal compilable `.tex` file from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that generates the problem. I assume that you have read the section on bibliographies in the manual `texdoc memoir`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'fields'. Do you mean author, title, date, journal, or do you mean the bob entries like 'Brambilla ...' and 'Yu ...'?

Answer (score 2):

When `memoir` is used with the `openbib` option, as it appears that the questioner has done, then the bibliography has extra vertical spaces. For a regular looking bibliography do not use the `openbib` option:

```
\documentclass[
 % options but not openbib
 ] {memoir}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @ Peter Wilson

I have checked my MWE, in the first command where I define the class of the document there was an `openbib` option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno,openbib]{memoir}
```

So I just removed it and the Bibliography looks normal again.

Comment: Had you provided an MWE showing that you had used the `openbib` option then I could have given you an answer sooner, but as it was nobody had any idea what you had done.